# How to present common foreign words in fiction?

Tags: fiction, style, creative-writing

In a story I use the Japanese words *konnichiwa* and *kawaii*:

> "*Konnichiwa!*" greeted a voice.
>
> "Wanna cuddle with a cutie for a couple of minutes?" She beamed a 
>   kittenish *kawaii* smile.

I thought most people would understand these, so I didn't add a translation. Instead, I added verbs and adjectives that hint to their meaning a bit.

Is this a right approach? If not, what's a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, whatever you do, don't convolute the the sentences around those words. Voices don't greet. People greet. `"Konnichiwa!" greeted a voice.` is grating and unnatural.

There are at least four things you can do that will not sound artificial and grating:

1. Just use the word. People can deduce the meaning from context or look it up if they don't get it. `"Konnichiwa!" a voice said.`
2. Translate the word and tell us what the original language was: `"Hello" a voice said in Japanese.`
3. Establish the use of formatting, such as italics, as an indication of the use of Japanese. Then use the English word in italics for all Japanese conversation from then one: "*Hello!*" a voice said in Japanese.
4. Use the Japanese word and provide the translation: `"Konnichiwa!" a voice said. Konnichiwa is hello in Japanese.` You are telling a story and there is absolutely nothing wrong with explaining things like this to the reader occasionally. Obviously this does not work for extended conversations in the foreign languages. Only option 3 really works for that.

Comment: Although I upvoted your answer because I agree with most of what you say, I think voices can greet e.g. the voice that greeted him was frosty.

Comment: I disagree with Mark Baker. I don't know what *Konnichiwa* means, and I need an explanation for that word to make sense to me. Replacing "said" with "greeted" is an elegant, unobtrusive way to explain the meaning of the direct speech.I disagree. I don't know what *Konnichiwa* means, and I need an explanation. It is completely normal

Comment: This is the difficult thing about writing. You can be right and wrong at the same time.